# Find the missing number from an array the efficient way

Tags: arrays, swift, big-o

I am trying to find an efficient way to solve the find a missing number from an array. I implemented the following way it's O(n). Please write any codes that efficiently solves this, just for learning purpose.

```
func findMissingNo(arrA: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    let firstIndex = arrA.first ?? 0
    let lastIndex = arrA.last ?? 0
    let rslt = Array(firstIndex...lastIndex)
    let missingNoArray = rslt.filter{ !arrA.contains($0)}
    return missingNoArray
}
findMissingNo(arrA: [11,12,14,15,16,18]) // Prints [13, 17] by looping 9 times
```

Comment: Why don't you simply iterate and increment the value each time, and keep only the values not found? That would avoid you creating a whole new array with all elements and filter on each element (which my take some times)...

Comment: Are you assuming that the array is always sorted, has no duplicate elements, and has at least 2 elements? If so, then the time complexity cannot be better than O(a - b) where a and b are the last and first elements of the array respectively. You at least need that much time to create the output in the worst case.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes In this case array not holds any duplicates and at least 2 elements.

Comment: @Larme You method is seems like effective for to find only 1 missing number.. Anyway can you put the solution in code.. if you can..

Comment: It finds one missing number: Not necessary. I've given a "simplified" version of the algorithm, but of course, it can be changed, for edges cases, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickly written and tested (in terms of times performances against your code, but not in term of possible edges cases/mistakes, for instance, if array is `0...10`, it won't work, but I'll let you work on the edges cases, since I focused mainly on the main cases, cases which might be covered during an edit and the end of the question)

Your current code:

```
func findMissingNo(arrA: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    let firstIndex = arrA.first ?? 0
    let lastIndex = arrA.last ?? 0
    let rslt = Array(firstIndex...lastIndex)
    let missingNoArray = rslt.filter{ !arrA.contains($0)}
    return missingNoArray
}
let numberArray = [11,12,14,15,18]
let missing1 = findMissingNo(arrA: numberArray)
print("Missing1: \(missing1)")
```

My attempt:

```
func findMissingNo2(arrA: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var missingNumbers: [Int] = []
    guard arrA.count > 2 else { return missingNumbers }
    for i in 0...arrA.count-2 {
        var current = arrA[i]
        let next = arrA[i+1]
        if next != current + 1 {
            current += 1
            while current != next {
                missingNumbers.append(current)
                current += 1
            }
        }
    }
    return missingNumbers
}


let missing2 = findMissingNo2(arrA: numberArray)
print("Missing1: \(missing2)")
```

Creating a big batch:

```
var array = Array(0...1000)
for _ in 0...10 {
    if let index = array.indices.randomElement() {
        let value = array.remove(at: index)
        print("removed: \(value)") //To check just in case that's the good value returned by the methods
    }
}
```

Testing:

```
let date1 = Date()
for _ in 0...100 {
    let missing = findMissingNo(arrA: array)
    print(missing)
}
print(Date().timeIntervalSince(date1)) //18.617565035820007

let date2 = Date()
for _ in 0...100 {
    let missing = findMissingNo2(arrA: array)
    print(missing)
}
print(Date().timeIntervalSince(date2)) //0.09566605091094971

print("---End")
print("")
```

For the time, I got: `18.857954025268555` vs `0.09159696102142334`, a big factor difference (~200 times).

Why is there such a big difference?

Because of

```
let missingNoArray = rslt.filter{ !arrA.contains($0)}
```

It means:
for each number in result, check if arrayA contains that number.
->
for each number in result, for each number in arrayA (with a stop condition, so it's not a full iteration, but "almost" in term of complexity) check if there is a match... 
Here there is a "double" (which is in fact not double, but n?) iteration that you missed.

I tested first with bigger value (array from "0 to 100000"), but it was taking too much time, with that "low number of values", the difference can already be seen.

Instead, you could use a `Set`:

```
let missingNoArray = Array(Set(rslt).subtracting(Set(arrA))).sorted()
```

It's faster than you method in my tests, (double my solution (0.21 ~ 0.22) in time performances), but still much faster than yours.
I added the `sorted()`, which may or may not be important in your solution, but will add time consumption since `Set` aren't ordered.

For the edges cases (ie: `[3]`, `[3, 4]`, `[3, 8]`)

```
guard arrA.count > 2 else { return missingNumbers }
```

==>

```
guard !arrA.isEmpty else { return [] }
guard arrA.count > 2 else {
    if arrA[0] + 1 >= arrA[1] {
        return []
    } else {
        return Array((arrA[0] + 1)...arrA[1]).dropLast() //Because last will be arrA[1] which is present)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation bro.. Your attempt is better since it stops iterating the array when you found the missing one. Set method also effective. Thanks

Comment: I added the edges cases for my "solution".

Comment: But if you have `[5, 500]`, you'd expect more items that the number of items in original array, no?

Answer (score 0):

An array A consisting of N different integers is given. The array contains integers in the range [1..(N + 1)], which means that exactly one element is missing.

My solution was:

```
public func solution(_ A : inout [Int]) -> Int {
    var missingNumber = A.first ?? 0 
    var tempArray = [Int](repeating: 0, count: A.count + 2)
    for element in A {
        tempArray[element] = 1
    }
    for (index, tempElement) in tempArray.enumerated() {
        if index == 0 {
            continue
        }
        if tempElement == 0 {
            missingNumber = index
            break
        }
    }
    return missingNumber
}
```